# Unable To Log In - Won't Accept Password

Tags: login, password

Ubuntu has started rejecting my password when I log in. Not a new installation; I have been able to log in until now. Any suggestions for recovery with current installation? Is it possible to install newer version of Ubuntu without losing projects and data? I started to try this, but it looked as though I would lose all data.

Please note that I am not a power user. Although I did not see any questions that precisely matched mine, the replies I saw were way over my head. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Jim

Comment: Have you tried resetting the password?

Answer (score 0):

Reboot. If you can see the GRUB menu, choose `Advanced options for Ubuntu` and select one of the "recovery mode" entries. You will see a menu like this:

[image]

Choose the `root` entry.
In the prompt that appears enter these commands:

```
mount -o rw,remount /
passwd <USER>
```

Replace `<USER>` with your username.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem - correct password rejected. I had two keyboard layouts loaded as options in settings/Keyboard/Input Sources. For some reason, on start-up, gnome 3 randomly started setting itself to a US config rather than "English (UK)" (maybe something that I did). As my password had an "@" symbol, the password was being entered incorrectly. After trying about 10 times with the same password, it let me back in. I deleted the US keyboard config.